# Java Springboot @Autowired Mybatis Mapper is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, jetty, mybatis

Autowired mapper in service is null.

There is mapper - VaMapper.java

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface VaMapper {
    int getSiteVa(ParameterMap param) throws Exception;
}
```

There is service class. - VaService.java

```
@Service
public class VaService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VaService.class);

    @Autowired
    public VaMapper vaMapper; //This mapper is null

    public void handlVaInfo(JSONObject vaObj) throws Exception{
        String vaHost = vaObj.get("vaHost").toString();
        System.out.println("vaHost:"+vaHost);
        int a = vaMapper.getSiteVa(new ParameterMap());
    }
```

And I want to use this service on below class. - SimpleEchoSocket.java

```
@WebSocket(maxTextMessageSize = 64 * 1024)
public class SimpleEchoSocket{

    public VaServiceva vaService(){
        return new VaService();
    }

    

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessageBuffer(Session session, byte[] byteArray, int offset, int length) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("onMessageBuffer");
        String vaHost = session.getRemoteAddress().toString().replaceAll("/", "");
        System.out.println("vaHost:"+vaHost);

        int thisIdx = -1;
        JSONObject thisObj = null;

        for(int i=0; i<vaArray.size(); i++){
            JSONObject vaObj = (JSONObject) vaArray.get(i);
            if(vaObj.get("vaHost").toString().equals(vaHost)){
                vaObj.put("plateImg", byteArray);
                thisIdx = i;
                thisObj = vaObj;

                break;
            }
        }
        if(thisIdx != -1){
            vaArray.remove(thisIdx);
            vaService().handlVaInfo(thisObj);
        }

    }
}
```

However NullPointerExcpetion occured like below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.iimp.pom.mapper.va.VaMapper.getSiteVa(com.iimp.pom.util.ParameterMap)" because "this.vaMapper" is null
    at com.iimp.pom.service.va.VaService.getSiteVa(VaService.java:50)
    at com.iimp.pom.va.VaProcessor.handlVaInfo(VaProcessor.java:44)
    at com.iimp.pom.socket.SimpleEchoSocket.onMessageBuffer(SimpleEchoSocket.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.CallableMethod.call(CallableMethod.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.OptionalSessionCallableMethod.call(OptionalSessionCallableMethod.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.onBinaryMessage(JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleBinaryMessage.messageComplete(SimpleBinaryMessage.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.onBinaryFrame(JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parseSingleFrame(Parser.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
...
```

As Denuim said, SimpleEchoSocket is managed by jetty not springboot.
But I think I succeed to load VaService on SimpleEchoSocket.

I changed code for load mapper instead of autowired.
However VaMapper is abstract, so I can't load mapper just like that.

How can I load vaMapper on VaService?

Please help me.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are those the only logs of you application?

Comment: Actually they're not. After some processing, data will be stored in db. I haven't been able to implement the code because I haven't moved on to the next stage yet.

Comment: `SimpleEchoSocket` isn't managed by Spring but Jetty and thus `@Autowired` isn't applied.

Comment: Thank you Denium. I'm totally newbie about jetty. So I hope you understand even if I ask a stupid question. Then is there any way I can use VaService inside SimpleEchoSocket?

Comment: It doesn't matter that VaMapper is abstract, Spring will create an implementation for you and inject that implementation into your VaMapper in SimpleEchoSocket. (If Mybatis-Spring is configured properly, for instance using MyBatis-Spring-Boot-Starter.)

Comment: Thanks, @Stijn, then why vaMapper is null in vaService when it called from SimpleEchoSocket? :’(

Comment: Your VaMapper should not have the `@Repository` annotation. If you remove that, hopefully it'll work or you'll get a clearer error message.

Comment: @Stijn, I tried as you said, but It didn't work.. Still getting the same error. I appreciate though